# UITableView with expanded row when one cell contains multiple objects

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am making an Ipad app that has a full-screen overview screen of what the user just entered.

It's a tableview that gets its data from core data via a NSFetchedResultsController and that shows it like a dataview (kind of like an excell sheet but with sections)

Example:

```
**Name**   **Tel**   **Hobbies**     **HobbyCost**   **...**

 **A**
 AName1      Tel1        Hobby1         $10           ....
 AName2      Tel2        Hobby1         $20           ....
```

The problem I have is trying to display a person that has multiple hobbies.
I'd like to show extra rows in the tableview for it only showing the hobby and leaving the rest blank like so:

```
 **B**
BName1       Tel1        Hobby1         $15           ....
                         Hobby2         $9            
                         Hobby3         $5            
BName2       Tel2        Hobby1         $20           ....
```

I've found numerous expanding table examples but they always have an object for each row.
Is this anything NSFetchedResultsController could help me with or am I just overseeing some easy way out?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is that to set Name,Tel and HobbyCost values along with Hobbies to every object that you are created.

NSManagedObject *en = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [en setValue:@"BName1" forKey:@"Name"];
        [en setValue:@"Tel1" forKey:@"Tel"];
        [en setValue:@Hobby1" forKey:@"Hobbies"];
        [en setValue:@"$15" forKey:@"Hobbycost"];

```
    [en setValue:@"BName1" forKey:@"Name"];
    [en setValue:@"Tel1" forKey:@"Tel"];
    [en setValue:@Hobby2" forKey:@"Hobbies"];
    [en setValue:@"$9" forKey:@"Hobbycost"];

    [en setValue:@"BName1" forKey:@"Name"];
    [en setValue:@"Tel1" forKey:@"Tel"];
    [en setValue:@Hobby3" forKey:@"Hobbies"];
    [en setValue:@"$5" forKey:@"Hobbycost"];
```